# List down Linux parent processes having more than 5 Child Processes

Tags: linux, process

I want to list all the parent processes on my machine which are having more than a number say(5) child process. Kindly suggest a command to achieve this.

Comment: Hi! that boils down to a whole chain of commands, not just one command. I don't think a single command that does this exists.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, Though a small script will be helpful.

Comment: Are you talking of children only, or grand (-grand...) children as well?

Comment: I think let's keep it simple..if parent has 5 decedents then we can list it out.